# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Invalid src prop - Firebase & Next,js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm creating a Next.js app that pulls information from a Firestore database. I have connected the database successfully, and the data is feeding into my app. Now, what is not working, is the image `{marketplaceTile}`.

Images are uploaded to FireStore, and pulled into each document with string, which passes the URL.

I have whitelisted the source in the next.config.js file like so:

```
module.exports = {
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
              protocol: 'https',
              hostname: 'firebasestorage.googleapis.com',
              port: '',
              pathname: '/**',
            },
          ],
    },
};
```

But I get an error message that tells me this:
"Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Invalid src prop (URL) on `next/image`, hostname "firebasestorage.googleapis.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: [https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host"](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host%22)

The database is being connected like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        ;(async () => {
            const colRef = collection(db, 'products')
            const snapshots = await getDocs(colRef)
            const docs = snapshots.docs.map((doc) => {
                const data = doc.data()
                data.id = doc.id
                return data
            })

            setProducts(docs)

            console.log(docs)
        })()
    }, [])
```

and my Products component looks like this:

```
function Product({ id, title, price, description, category, marketplaceTile }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const addItemToBasket = () => {
    const product = {
      id,
      title,
      price,
      description,
      category,
      gameCover,
      marketplaceTile,
      developer,
    };
    console.log(product)

    //Sending the product as an action to the REDUX store (aka. Basket Slice)
    dispatch(addToBasket(product));
  };

  return (
    <div>
<Image src={marketplaceTile} height={200} width={200} className="mx-auto object-contain" alt="Product Image"/>

      <h4 className="my-3 text-gray">{title}</h4>
</div>
```

where `marketplaceTile` is the image I'm trying to pull in.

Is there anybody who can point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you have a look at my answer?

Comment: @RohitKharche I highly appreciate you taking the time to respond. We switched to a different database for this project, since the solutions we could find online did not work in this particular instance. 
Your solution might work in other instances, in this case it didn't.
Again, I highly appreciate your response, and the time you took to draft it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not mentioned the pathname for the images

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  images: {
    formats: ['image/avif', 'image/webp'],
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'firebasestorage.googleapis.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/image/upload/**',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Also check whether the image url is not null.And also see the [github link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18311) which may be helpful.